# ASP.NET MVC 4 autocomplete not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

Hello I have a simple MVC autocomplete, the code I tested and it works when I create an "empty" mvc project, but when I do the exact code in intenet application it does not work, It never gets to autocomplete method. any ideas? so wired. Thank you

Home controller

```
static List<Students> _students = new List<Students>() { 
        new Students{id=1,Name="Bob", Grade="B"},
        new Students{id=2,Name="Billy", Grade="A"},
        new Students{id=3,Name="Mike", Grade="B"}
    };

    public ActionResult AutoMethod(string term)
    {
       //....
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_students);
    }
```

index view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Students>

  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     $("#searchText").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("AutoMethod")'
    });

});
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
     @Html.TextBox("searchText");
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
      </th>
      <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Grade)
      </th>

  </tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
      <tr>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
          </td>
      </tr>
  }
```

Comment: I noticed if I remove the line: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") from layout file it works. If I add the two js file to the "jquery bundle" it doesnt work.. can someone explain how to fix it, to budle all together? and why it is doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look at the resulting HTML code in your browser, probably you are referencing JavaScript files more than once. It is not advised to reference commonly used JavaScript files from views; use your `_SiteLayour.cshtml` or MVC's "[Bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)" feature instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to top of your autocomplete code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'></script>
```

And add `jQuery.noConflict();` to your function:

```
 $(function () {
     jQuery.noConflict();
     $("#searchText").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("AutoMethod")'
    });
```